# Load WebView links in another webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in my app . i want the webview links (when clicked) be load  in another webview .
here is a part of my code.links in webview1 are loaded in devise browser :

```
        webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                webView2.loadUrl(url);
                //webView2.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
        };
        webView1.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.
Just to prevent loading links in device default browser you should set webview client to:

```
webView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the URL in another activity use this :
On activity1.java add this . ( am using a button to move from acticity to activity )

**Activity1.java**

***Declare :***

```
Button button;
```

***Below oncrete :***

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

***After Oncreate :***

```
public void onClick1(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
        //Passing a URL to activity2
        intent.putExtra("WebAddress","http://www.techmobs.in");
        Activity1.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**XML part of Activity1.java**

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:onClick="onClick1"
                android:text="Blogging" />
```

**Activity2.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class Website extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    String urlopen;
    private Toolbar mActionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Getting the URL from activity1.java
        final String WebAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra("WebAddress");

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameprogress);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                setTitle("Loading...");

                if(progress == 100){
                    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setTitle(view.getTitle());
                    urlopen = WebAddress;

                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
            }
        });
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl(WebAddress);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);

    }
    //Help client class definition
    class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)       {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else {
         super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**XML for Activity2.java :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.yourpackage.Activity2">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameprogress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="3dp">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
            android:progress="30"/>
    </FrameLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**For custom progress bar :**
Add it on drawables on the name custom_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="3dip" />
                    <solid android:color="#4FC3F7" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>
        <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="3dip" />
                    <solid android:color="#4FC3F7" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

I hope this would help you . this would give an amazing look for your webview For more such visit http://www.techmobs.in